# Can we restrict user access from a resource group?

Tags: azure, rbac

I have multiple resource groups in azure but only want to restrict users to 1. Don't want to have to manually assign user to all resource but one so wondering if it can be done the opposite way?

Answer (score 2):

yes, you need to remove users permissions on the subscription level and grant them permissions on the resource group level.

Reading:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview

Comment: but then i would need to add them into every resource group.
If i have 100 resource groups but dont want user to access 1 resource group. i would need to add all these users to resource groups. 

What i really want to do is just remove them from this 1 resource group

Comment: no, you cannot do that in an easy fashion. there is no block inheritance option. so you have only 1 way of doing this - being granular, creating some script that autoassign access to certain user\groups but skip others. you have pretty much the same problem with custom roles.

Comment: Wouldn't using an ARM template easily work for this? Allowing all and deny the specific resource group...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216764/azure-arm-policy-to-deny-resource-group-without-tags
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48284885/can-i-apply-permissions-through-an-arm-template

Comment: you cant really remove permissions with arm template, you cant really remove anything with arm template, unless you use complete mode, but, i doubt that would work for permissiions @Rthomas529

Comment: That's unfortunate. This is quite simply achieve in AWS through the IAM templates.

Comment: might be, i'm no aws expert :) @Rthomas529